# Is there a method to avoid user drag edge from anchor?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I want to make a graph editor using mxgraph.

I want to connect two vertices using "pipeline" that I defined myself, but not using dragging edge from anchor of one vertex. I made some srceenshots below.

**I don't want to drag edge from anchor**

[image: I don't want to drag edge from anchor]

**I don't want to drag edge from anchor**

[image: I don't want to drag edge from anchor]

**I only want to connect two vertices using "pipeline" arrow line**

[image: I only want to connect two vertices using "pipeline" arrow line]

So, is there any methods to avoid dragging edge from a vertex.
BTW I want to keep anchors, because I want to use them for arrow lines connecting vertices.

What I tried now:

```js
mxConnectionHandlerInsertEdge = mxConnectionHandler.prototype.insertEdge;
mxConnectionHandler.prototype.insertEdge = function (parent, id, value, source, target, style) {
    return null;
};
```

I add this codes in my program, I found I can prevent the edge dragging from anchor connecting two vertices (when I release my mouse the dragging edge disappeared), **BUT** there is still a preview of dragging edge from anchor which is what I don't want see.

So any smart guys can help me?
Thanks a lot~